# How to fixate header with drop-down menu?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, fixed

I have fixed header with drop-down menu. But i have problem with menu, because it is higher then view port, and with fixed position i cannot scroll it. 
you can see how it works now on my github https://katehrybkova.github.io/ET/index.html#

I tried to change menu-position to absolute, but in this way, when i scroll down, and push menu button - menu starts no from top of viewport but of top of my page.

```html
<div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="idishka" />
      <label for="idishka" class="inline"> </label>

      <div class="menuBlock">...
      </div>

      <header>
      </header>
</div>
```

```css
.menuBlock {
  position: fixed;
 left: -100%;
}
#idishka:checked ~ .menuBlock {
  left: 0;
}
header {
  position: sticky;
}
#idishka:checked ~ header {
position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try put `position: fixed` on your header.
Take a look on this [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but it doesnt helps, because i cannot scroll my menu. It is the main problem